# How to get the count for a particular key in the dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

My content inside a dictionary is below

I need to now for `BusinessArea` how many different `name` key is there,  like this need to know Designation also

```
test=
[ { 'masterid': '1', 'name': 'Group1', 'BusinessArea': [ { 'id': '14', 'name': 'Accounting', 'parentname': 'Finance'}, { 'id': '3', 'name': 'Research', 'parentname': 'R & D' } ], 'Designation': [ { 'id': '16', 'name': 'L1' }, { 'id': '20', 'name': 'L2' }, { 'id': '25', 'name': 'L2' }] }, 

{ 'masterid': '2', 'name': 'Group1', 'BusinessArea': [ { 'id': '14', 'name': 'Research', 'parentname': '' }, { 'id': '3', 'name': 'Accounting', 'parentname': '' } ], 'Role': [ { 'id': '5032', 'name': 'Tester' }, { 'id': '5033', 'name': 'Developer' } ], 'Designation': [ { 'id': '16', 'name': 'L1' }, { 'id': '20', 'name': 'L2' }, { 'id': '25', 'name': 'L2' }]},

 { 'masterid': '3', 'name': 'Group1', 'BusinessArea': [ { 'id': '14', 'name': 'Engineering' }, { 'id': '3', 'name': 'Engineering', 'parentname': '' } ], 'Role': [ { 'id': '5032', 'name': 'Developer' }, { 'id': '5033', 'name': 'Developer', 'parentname': '' } ], 'Designation': [ { 'id': '16', 'name': 'L1' }, { 'id': '20', 'name': 'L2' }, { 'id': '25', 'name': 'L2' }]}]
```

I want to get the count of masterid of BusinessArea and Designation which is all the names

Expected out is below

```
[
  {
    "name": "BusinessArea",
    "values": [
      {
        "name": "Accounting",
        "count": "2"
      },
      {
        "name": "Research",
        "count": "2"
      },
      {
        "name": "Engineering",
        "count": "1"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Designation",
    "values": [
      {
        "name": "L1",
        "count": "3"
      },
      {
        "name": "l2",
        "count": "3"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
res=[{'name': 'BusinessArea', 'values': []}, {'name': 'Designation', 'values': []}]

listbus=sum([i['BusinessArea'] for i in test], [])
listdes=sum([i['Designation'] for i in test], [])

res[0]['values']=[{'name':i, 'count':0} for i in set(k['name'] for k in listbus)]
res[1]['values']=[{'name':i, 'count':0} for i in set(k['name'] for k in listdes)]

for i in listbus:
    for k in range(len(res[0]['values'])):
        if i['name']==res[0]['values'][k]['name']:
            res[0]['values'][k]['count']+=1

for i in listdes:
    for k in range(len(res[1]['values'])):
        if i['name']==res[1]['values'][k]['name']:
            res[1]['values'][k]['count']+=1

>>> print(res)
[{'name': 'BusinessArea', 'values': [{'name': 'Accounting', 'count': 2}, {'name': 'Research', 'count': 2}, {'name': 'Engineering', 'count': 2}]}, {'name': 'Designation', 'values': [{'name': 'L1', 'count': 3}, {'name': 'L2', 'count': 6}]}]
```

Comment: This includes duplicate names into the counts, which is different to the expected output.

Comment: Question looks for unique 'names' but doesn't ask for count of unique 'masterid' @Nons can you please clarify that?

Comment: it is unique names, i need Engineering to `1`. Can you check below one also

Comment: test=
[ { 'masterid': '1', 'name': 'Group1', 'BusinessArea': [ 'Accounting','Research'], 'Designation': [ 'L1' 'L2' ] }, 

{ 'masterid': '2', 'name': 'Group1', 'BusinessArea': ['Research','Accounting' ], 'Role': [ { 'id': '5032', 'name': 'Tester' }, { 'id': '5033', 'name': 'Developer' } ], 'Designation': [ 'L1' 'L2' ]},

 { 'masterid': '3', 'name': 'Group1', 'BusinessArea': [ 'Engineering' ], 'Role': [ { 'id': '5032', 'name': 'Developer' }, { 'id': '5033', 'name': 'Developer', 'parentname': '' } ], 'Designation': [ 'L1'  'L2' ]}]

Comment: can you check above one also if my BusinessArea and Designation is in list

Comment: My solution returns unique 'names' but doesn't care for uniqueness of id's Is this what you want or you want unique id's? For example in test this one is found 3 times: `{ 'id': '20', 'name': 'L2' }` for Designation. Do you want it to count as 3 or just 1?

Comment: i need return return the masterid count, so L2 and L1 is 3, Engineering is 1

Answer (score 0):

You could count unique names using a nested [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```py
from collections import defaultdict
from json import dumps

keys = ["BusinessArea", "Designation"]

group_counts = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))
for group in test:
    for key in keys:
        names = [item["name"] for item in group[key]]
        unique_names = list(dict.fromkeys(names))
        for name in unique_names:
            group_counts[key][name] += 1

print(dumps(group_counts, indent=2))
```

Which will give you these counts:

```json
{
  "BusinessArea": {
    "Accounting": 2,
    "Research": 2,
    "Engineering": 1
  },
  "Designation": {
    "L1": 3,
    "L2": 3
  }
}
```

Then you could modify the result to get the list of dicts you expect:

```py
result = [
    {
        "name": name,
        "values": [{"name": value, "count": count} for value, count in counts.items()],
    }
    for name, counts in group_counts.items()
]

print(dumps(result, indent=2))
```

Which gives you this:

```json
[
  {
    "name": "BusinessArea",
    "values": [
      {
        "name": "Accounting",
        "count": 2
      },
      {
        "name": "Research",
        "count": 2
      },
      {
        "name": "Engineering",
        "count": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Designation",
    "values": [
      {
        "name": "L1",
        "count": 3
      },
      {
        "name": "L2",
        "count": 3
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: can you check once if my dictionary is list test= [ { 'masterid': '1', 'name': 'Group1', 'BusinessArea': [ 'Accounting','Research'], 'Designation': [ 'L1' 'L2' ] }, { 'masterid': '2', 'name': 'Group1', 'BusinessArea': ['Research','Accounting' ], 'Role': [ { 'id': '5032', 'name': 'Tester' }, { 'id': '5033', 'name': 'Developer' } ], 'Designation': [ 'L1' 'L2' ]}, { 'masterid': '3', 'name': 'Group1', 'BusinessArea': [ 'Engineering' ], 'Role': [ { 'id': '5032', 'name': 'Developer' }, { 'id': '5033', 'name': 'Developer', 'parentname': '' } ], 'Designation': [ 'L1' 'L2' ]}]